# Swift: Using toolbar button to delete multiple cells in a TableView

Tags: swift, uitableview, button, cell, uitoolbar

I am currently working on a todo app using core data. The user is able to mark todos as completed. Now, I want to add a button to the toolbar which supposes to delete every marked todo on a single tab. I already configured swipe actions to delete and mark on cell at a time. I cant provide any code for this situation, simply because I got no specific idea how to implement this. The code provided down below shows how I configured the delete swipe. Maybe this can help to come up with a solution.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
               trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration?
{

    let deleteAction = UIContextualAction(style: .destructive, title:  "Delete", handler: { (ac:UIContextualAction, view:UIView, success:(Bool) -> Void) in

        //Haptic Feedback
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(1519)

        //Animation
        let range = NSMakeRange(0, self.tableView.numberOfSections)
        let sections = NSIndexSet(indexesIn: range)
        self.tableView.reloadSections(sections as IndexSet, with: .fade)

        //Call delete function from CoreDataManager.swift
        let todo = CoreDataManager.shared.getTodoItem(index: indexPath.row)
        CoreDataManager.shared.deleteItems(item2: todo)
        tableView.reloadData()
        success(true)
    })
    deleteAction.image = UIImage(named: "trash1")
    deleteAction.backgroundColor = .red

    return UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [deleteAction])
}
```

Comment: How do you keep a reference to `every marked todo`

Comment: If a todo is tabbed, it will be marked as completed. This information is stored in the core data. My idea was something like: if (todo.completed = true){.....}

Answer (score 0):

You should fetch all todo from core data by checking `completed = true` and iterate each `todo` and call `CoreDataManager.shared.deleteItems(item2: todo)`

```
guard let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate)?.persistentContainer.viewContext else {
    return
}

do {
    let fetchRequest : NSFetchRequest<Todo> = Todo.fetchRequest()
    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "completed == 1")
    let fetchedResults = try context.fetch(fetchRequest) as? [NSManagedObject]
    fetchedResults.forEach { context.delete($0) }
    try context.save()
}
catch {
    print("Error with request: \(error)")
}
```